# JavaFX application "Unable to invoke method" / "Unable to launch JVM"

Tags: java, javafx, wix

We've got a JavaFX 2 application developed in NetBeans 8.0.2, being packaged for deployment with WiX 3.9.1208, but we are having a problem on a few seemingly random machines.

After installing, when attempting to run the application, a dialog box is shown with the name of the executable and "Unable to invoke method" in the title. After clicking OK, the same box is shown again but with "Unable to launch JVM" in the title.

We are bundling Java 8u45 32-bit with the MSI, and everything seems to work on most machines, but we have had the above issue a couple of times on users machines, across WinXP, Win7 32-bit and Win8.1 64-bit running on a Mac in Parallels. Doesn't seem to make a difference whether Java is already installed on the users machine or not, and we can't figure out what could we causing the problem.

We haven't customised the WiX deployment in any way, just used what was out the box to start with, and we have very little experience in deploying Java applications.

We've been unable to reproduce this issue on any of our setups. Thanks in advance for any ideas on what could be happening!

Regards,
Richard